# Creating lat/lon grid in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I'm using QGIS.

How can I create a shapefile consisting of a grid 0.5° latitude and 1° longitude in size?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use the MMQGIS plugin, after installing you find it in qgis 1.8 under plugins--mmqgis. select create --create grid layer and enter the appropriate values[image]

for h spacing and v spacing select 1 or 0.5 (instead of 10 in my screenshot)

hope this helps

Comment: MMQGIS-plugin is availabel via official user contributed plugins http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed, but you may also take a look at the pugins homepage http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/. this is an extrem useful plugin!

Answer (score 12):

Another option is to use the built-in Vector Grid tool. (Toolbar menu: Vector → Research → Vector Grid):

[image: Vector Grid window]

Comment: Is this guaranteed to be in line with the real latitude and longitude lines? I didn't see how they choose where to start the lines.

Comment: The grid starts at xmin,ymin and next coordinates are chosen by adding the specified horizinal/vertical spacing. The code that creates the grid is here https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/Grid.py

Comment: Thanks! I ended up downloading a file with the lines I needed from Natural Earth.