# How to georeference a map - which is in projected coordinate system - using geographic lat long?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, georeferencing

We have some hard copy maps which were projected in Gauss Kruger coordinate system (in the legend it has been mentioned). But, the coordinates were given in Geographic lat long (Beijing 1954). In Global mapper, if we enter the geographic lat long and change the projection, it will change the coordinates accordingly & will detect the Zone too. Is there any such thing in QGIS or even in ArcGIS.

We have tried by assigning geographic lat long (Beijing 1954) to the data frame (Default CRS in the case of QGIS) and entered the geographic lat long and tried with the Target CRS as Gauss Kruger projection. But still, it doesn't convert the coordinates correctly.

All i can see is, first we have to georeference the image in Geographic lat long and then we have to reproject (Warp in case of QGIS) the image. Is there any other options available ?

Comment: I think so, it reads almost exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

[Geo- referencing Projected coordinated raster with GCS - ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97702/geo-referencing-projected-coordinated-raster-with-gcs-arcgis/97748#97748)

this looks like exactly the same question. I don't know how to mark as duplicate.

Comment: To mark as a duplicate just hit the close button underneath a Question and choose the top option to enter the URL of the earlier Question.

Comment: Sorry, I see no *close* button, maybe I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Juz realised...that Geo- referencing Projected coordinated raster with GCS - ArcGIS question was asked by one of my colleagues. 

Do i have to delete this question or mark it as duplicate ?

Comment: You're right - its a privilege that kicks in at 3,000: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions  In the meantime if you spot a duplicate I think the best thing will be to flag it for moderator attention or just make a Comment and someone will probably spot it quite quickly

Comment: @saravanaganesh18 You could do either (I think) but I have already proposed that it be closed as a duplicate so with four other votes, or one from a moderator, that will probably happen quite quickly anyway.