# Creating LAT / LONG grid labels with Northing/Southing and Easting/Westing suffix in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, qgis-print-layouts

I´m using QGIS 3.6.

I have my map as you can see below:

[image]

I would like to have the labels in LAT / LONG coordinates like (40E ; -10S).

Can you please tell me how can I do this?

I saw:

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html

[Creating lat/lon grid in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30331/creating-lat-lon-grid-in-qgis)

But it does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 3):

In the item properties of your map in the print composer scroll down to the `Grids` section. Select your grid and press the `Modify Grid...`. Now scroll down to `Draw Coordinates`. The `Format` dropdown menu allows you to select the display format of the coorinates of your grid. From the dropdown select any item that includes **with suffix** to print the Northing/Southing and Easting/Westing with your coordinates.

[image]

This should give you the result you want. If your desired format is not in the dropdown list, select "custom" from the list and create your own format via the expression builder with the "E" button to the right of the dropdown menu.